# Using Java Streams to pull out a key from a list of maps, and create a map of a map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to move an item from inside a `Map` to outside the `Map`.

I'm trying to get the rowIdentifier out of the `List` below:

```
List<Map<Object,Object>>

// [{"rowIdentifier": "s5", "rowKey1": 5, "rowKey2": 7},{"rowIdentifier": "s7", "rowKey1": 9, "rowKey2": 9}]
```

into result `Map<Map<Object,Object>>`

```
// {"s5": {"rowKey1": 5, "rowKey2": 7}, "s7": {"rowKey1": 9, "rowKey2": 9}
```

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding `groupingBy` and `collect(Collectors.mapping)` vs. `Collectors.toMap` (I'm not sure I understand the difference between 'mapping' vs. 'toMap' functions in Java `Stream`s. Or if I even need that.

DictByRowIdentifier[r["rowIdentifier"]] is the way I'm planning on calling it later.

A lot of examples on the web seem to simply collect it to a `List` or a `Set`. They don't seem to throw it back into another `Map` so examples are hard to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your direct question, you want [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-), twice:

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<>(); // populated elsewhere
Map<String, Map<String, String>> mapOfMaps = listOfMaps.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.get("rowIdentifier"), 
            m -> m.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> !e.getKey().equals("rowIdentifier"))
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue))));
```

I changed the types to `String`, because that's what they are and it makes everything compile without warnings.

Comment: Incredible! I could not figure it out at all. I don't understand the documentation for collect() and then toMap vs mapping. I didn't think of the filter to remove the same key from downstream. Explains a lot. Thank you!